# Determining influence of continuous variable on binary outcome

Tags: binary-data, continuous-data, probit

I'm running data analysis for an online marketplace. I want to determine the influence of the time a perishable good (say a concert ticket) is online versus the probability of a sale.

I have made a plot showing that 'time online' is an important factor: items online for 2 days have 1.5x the probability of selling compared to 3 hours online. In what way can I prove this statistically?

I have looked into probit models. Is that the right way to go?

Comment: You can try [logit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logit) or [probit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probit) models for this. Based on the regression coefficients, you can find the actual impact of time on probability of selling.